# Is there a way to fork a repo but also keep the original repository's issues (GitHub)? (Issues are deleted as soon as you fork)

Tags: github, git-fork

I just forked a repository to work on a project, and the original repository had around 10 open issues.

So, as soon as I forked the repository, I can see that these issues are not available on my version of the project (forked). Is there any way to fork a repository but also keep the original issues?

Comment: How would this make sense? The issues are not issues on the fork. They are not yours to "keep".

Comment: @matt I agree that it doesn't make sense. The only thing is that this is a university project, where we have a main repository that my professor developed, and then we forked this one to work on the project. Thus, it would make sense to also have the issues in order to work on them :)

Comment: Issues (and PRs and other GitHub-fork-specific data) are stored *on* GitHub in a per-fork database, outside Git proper, so Git itself cannot help. GitHub could give you more direct access to the database through some rest API, but as far as I know they only give the access documented at GitHub's documentation. You could do whatever you can *within* that API.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your answer, it makes sense.

Comment: @torek Alright! Cool :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except if you want to have your own specific workflow,  there is no real need to have the issues all duplicated in your fork.

- You will indeed work with the issues of the upstream repository.
- You still can refer to the original issues with #idIssue.
- You will push your branch and create a pull request.
- When your PR will be created, the issues referenced will be automatically linked to your PR.
- Once the PR will be merged, the issue will be closed (automatically -- if you used the keyword 'Fixes' -- or manually by a maintainer).

All the projects using Github are working like that and that is good enough (until you want to do a hard fork because you really don't want to contribute to the upstream project)